# Pager system charging pin and socket

Tags: power, battery-charging, identification, pins

Does anyone know what these pins are called? This is a pager from paging system used in certain restaurants. I'd like to know what it's called as I want to use it in my device's design. I need to know what socket is used with it, but that would be easier to find if I can find the pin :)

[image]

Comment: It looks like a custom design - not something one can find off-the-shelf.

Comment: @Mike these type of pins are off the shelf components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They appear to be what is know by the brand name "pogo-pins", which I believe are officially called "spring contact pin".

Quite a few manufacturers do them. They tend to be expensive and have a low current rating compared to other contacts, but are useful in that they are so versatile, as only exposed metal is all that's required as a mating half. Often small ones are used on on test pads of PCBs to do production line tests.

EDIT: just noticed you ask to find the mating half in your question. This type of contact often just contact to a bit of metal in some custom designed housing. But they are also used with a proper contacter, which as a profile to match the pin (in this instance the pin has sharp spike, so the official mating half would have suitable cone indent in it).